# Center equation ignoring condition/remark

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

Really basic question, probably already answered but couldn't find anything.

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  x_j = 1,\quad y_j = 2,\quad z_j = 3 \qquad \text{for }j=1, 2, 3, \dots, n
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

What I get is this:

[image]

But I want something like this (the "for j"-part should be ignored when the equation is centered):

[image]

Probably it would look better, if the "for j"-part is aligned to the right margin, unfortunately I don't know how to do that, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just load `mathtools` instead of `amsmath` (it loads the latter) and use its `\mathrlap` command. You may put the `\qquad` inside the `\rlap` or not. In my opinion, if you put it inside, the main part of the equation doesn't look centred to the reader,though it is.

You must also be aware the condition might overlap the right margin. In such a case, I would one of the multi-line amsmath environment and put the condition on a separate line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  x_j = 1,\quad y_j = 2,\quad z_j = 3 \qquad\mathrlap{\text{for }j=1, 2, 3, \dots, n}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  x_j = 1,\quad y_j = 2,\quad z_j = 3 \mathrlap{\qquad\text{for }j=1, 2, 3, \dots, n}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  x_j = 1,\quad y_j = 2,\quad z_j = 3 \qquad \text{for }j=1, 2, 3, \dots, n
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd put the `\qquad` inside `\mathrlap`; one should be aware that the condition might stick outside the margin.

Comment: You're perfectly right. I'll change that at once, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could align the condition to the right margin and center the equation to the rest of the line using `flalign`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}% loads also amsmath

\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
&&x_j = 1,\quad y_j = 2,\quad z_j = 3 &&\text{for }j=1, 2, 3, \dots, n&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Only if you are sure that the equation and the condition will not overlap each other, you can use `\mathllap` to ignore the condition while centering the equation to the whole line.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}% loads also amsmath

\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
x_j = 1,\quad y_j = 2,\quad z_j = 3
\end{equation*}

\begin{flalign*}
&&x_j = 1,\quad y_j = 2,\quad z_j = 3 &&\mathllap{\text{for }j=1, 2, 3, \dots, n}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]